# cas-dc.cls documentclass - Font change from Charis to Calibri style

Tags: fonts

I am writing a double-column paper, using Elsevier CAS Bundle, cas-dc-template.tex and cas-d.cls which seems to load stix as the math font and charis as the text font. The journal requires a Calibri style font rather than the default Times Roman (charis) font as used in the cas-dc.cls.

Any suggestions on how to change the font style in this document class to a Calibri style font?

Thanks in advance.

```
% Fonts
%
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\file_if_exist:nTF { stix.sty }
{
  \file_if_exist:nTF { charis.sty }
  {
    \RequirePackage[notext]{stix} 
    \RequirePackage{charis}
  }
  { \RequirePackage{stix} }
}
{
  \iow_term:x {  *********************************************************** }
  \iow_term:x { ~Stix ~ and ~ Charis~ fonts ~ are ~ not ~ available ~ }
  \iow_term:x { ~ in ~TeX~system.~Hence~CMR~ fonts~ are ~ used. }
  \iow_term:x {  *********************************************************** }
}

\file_if_exist:nTF { inconsolata }
{ \RequirePackage[scaled=.85]{inconsolata} }
{ \tex_gdef:D \ttdefault { cmtt } }d
```

Comment: I agree this should be the journal's responsibility, but if you're using [this here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/) I don't see anything incompatible with using XeLaTeX with `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Calibri}\setsansfont{Calibri}` at the end of your preamble. If you're stuck with pdflatex the closest free font on CTAN is probably [Carlito](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/carlito/): `\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, appreciate it. I agree, however, the conference organizers only have a Word document as a basic template for their conference paper layout,  rather than the usual cas-dc_template.tex for an Elsevier journal paper. As they do fundamentally differ in their layout, I am struggling to find a Latex template that I can use as a general template. I have found a more appropriate double-column Latex template, ijcaArticle class file.

Comment: [ijcaArticle](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/author-submission-guide-and-template-for-international-journal-of-computer-applications-ijca/fwpbvktystjm)

Comment: Please forgive the basic coding questions, I have basic knowledge of modifying Latex code. In the ijcaArtice.cls, is this the code for the font style? `\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}`. I use Overleaf as my editor, any pointers to modifying the code to a type that resembles Calibri would be great. Thanks

Comment: Hi @frabjous, your code `\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}` once added to the end of the ijcaArticle.cls class file has worked, its a close Calibri style font. Thanks again.